# Does Cunning Stalker work if you're not adjacent to your target?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, reach

There is a feat on page 312 of *Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms* called *Cunning Stalker*. It says:

> You gain combat advantage against enemies that have no creatures adjacent to them other than you.

If I attack an enemy with a reach weapon, and no creatures are adjacent to them, do I get combat advantage? There certainly aren't any other creatures next to them.

Obviously the DM could rule that it works regardless of what the RAW say, but I'm the DM, and I need to determine if my GM PC should take this feat or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The rules-as-written are unclear in this case.

The clause "other than you" could be interpreted as meaning that you need to fulfill the condition of adjacency, but that no one else can. Or, it can be interpreted as meaning that no one can be adjacent, but you are an exception and can be adjacent if you like.

As far as I can tell, there's been no official word on how to interpret this, nor any kind of errata.

I read several forum threads on the issue: [1](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3391911) [2](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3264981) [3](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3357726) [4](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2981991) [5](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?297270-Interpreting-Cunning-Stalker-Feat-from-HotFK). There's no real consensus, but more people seem to think that you don't need to be adjacent. I wouldn't be surprised if this was because most people are players, and are biased towards being able to do something, rather than not being able to do it.

Multiple people contacted Wizards customer service, and got contradicting replies. Quoted from the forums:

**You don't need to be adjacent:**

> Thank you for getting in touch with us! The wording on Cunning Stalker is "Benefit: You gain combat advantage against enemies that have no creatures adjacent to them other than you." The only requirement is that no enemies be adjacent to the creature for you to gain combat advantage, nothing in the feat says anything about the character needing to be adjacent and so does not be and can gain combat advantage with ranged attacks. Of course your DM is free to change this if it makes the game more fun for the group!

**You do need to be adjacent:**

> Indeed it does. Cunning Stalker reads "You gain combat advantage against enemies that have no creatures adjacent to them *other than you*."

Therefore, this is one situation where the decision is entirely up to the DM and their group. I'll check with my group, and rule whatever their consensus is.

Comment: Could you show which forms those quotes came from?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can get Combat Advantage on attacks made while not adjacent. The only requirement is that other creatures not be adjacent. If you had to be adjacent it would have been worded like Hunter's Gaze[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13856), something like *"You gain combat advantage against enemies you are adjacent to that no other creatures are adjacent to."*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe it would work. The last part of the description ("...other than you") could be interpreted either way, but the the important part is earlier in the description, where it says "You gain combat advantage against enemies..." and not "You gain combat advantage against *adjacent* enemies..."

The final stipulation is merely stating you don't count when determining if there is a creature adjacent to them, meaning 'you get them when they're alone'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it works, because as you say there are no creatures adjacent to them.

I would read that condition as it needs to have no creatures adjacent to them with you as an exception to that rule, so if you are also not next to it they still have no creatures adjacent to them and the exception doesn't come into play.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey He understands what I'm asking. This is how I initially read it, but I can also see Erik's reading.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it doesn't work. You yourself *must* be adjacent to the target in order to be able to meet the requirement of "no creatures other than you".

Since there is no mention of attack type, this feat would otherwise also work when making ranged attacks against the target. Keep that in mind when you make a ruling on it.

Comment: Good point about the ranged attacks. That might be what sways me one way or the other.